# Passing multiple values into variable

Tags: sql-server, variables

I'm trying to pass a value from a table into a variable which I can then use in a query.  The problem is that I need the variable to have multiple values, which I've never done before.  Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

CompanyID has multiple values for control number.  How would I be able to pass multiple values into the variable?  The query I'm using is using Open Query so I can't join to a temp table.

```
 declare @t table( companyid int, control_number int)
 insert into @t
 values(5555, 777),
 (5555, 720),
 (5555, 234),
 (111, 345),
 (111, 356)

 select *
 from @t

 declare @CN int
 set @CN = (select control_number from @t where companyid = 5555)

 select *
 from @table
 where control_number IN(@CN)
```

Comment: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause) - [STRING_SPLIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36980115/5070879)

Comment: Use dynamic SQL

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to write this?

Comment: Why do you need to "store" the resulset of the first query AT ALL? Smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: And Erland discusses this misconception [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Comment: I'm not storing it.  I'm just providing data for people to use here.

Comment: Please check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60675669/4690672)

Comment: @Smor that is what I thought too

Comment: So I just realized that my SP is using an Open Query and I can't join to any temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it into variable you can directly use it **IN** like this :

```
declare @t table( companyid int, control_number int)
 insert into @t
 values(5555, 777),
 (5555, 720),
 (5555, 234),
 (111, 345),
 (111, 356)

 select *
 from @t

 select *
 from @table
 where control_number IN(select control_number from @t where companyid = 5555)
```

Try this out I haven't able to run this because you haven.t shared schema of `@table`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to skin the cat. Make your second variable a table variable. Then just join to it.

```
declare @CN table (cntNbr int)
insert @CN (cntNbr)
select control_number from @t where companyid = 5555;

select t.*
from @t as t
join @CN as c
  on c.cntNbr = t.control_number;
```

Rextester link: https://rextester.com/SCYCX42852

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 (Dynamic SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ( companyid INT, control_number INT )
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES (5555, 777),
(5555, 720),
(5555, 234),
(111, 345),
(111, 356)

SELECT * FROM #temp

DECLARE @controlNum VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @controlNum = ISNULL(@controlNum + ', ', '') + CAST(control_number AS VARCHAR) FROM #temp WHERE companyid = 5555

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE control_number IN ( ' + @controlNum + ')'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Method 2:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE( companyid INT, control_number INT )
INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES (5555, 777),
(5555, 720),
(5555, 234),
(111, 345),
(111, 356)

SELECT * FROM @temp

SELECT * FROM @temp WHERE control_number IN (SELECT control_number FROM @temp WHERE companyid = 5555)
```